# Finding the most popular tags on Careers

Tags: support, tags, search, jobs, sorting

I am trying to find the tags on Stack Overflow Careers that have the most jobs. On most Stack Exchange sites, I can easily do this by clicking on the "Tags" link from the home page, but I don't see this link on Careers. How can I view the most popular tags?

**EDIT:** I tried accessing the URL https://careers.stackoverflow.com/tags and that didn't work.

Comment: I asked this on meta.stackoverflow.com, thinking that was the right place. I somehow missed the much larger number of questions on meta.stackexchange.com. Sorry about this.

Comment: No worries; that's why we have migration. Normally, you can ask these questions on any site - but I want to make sure the Careers team sees it.

Comment: Such option does not exist because Careers doesn't have real "tags", but rather using the tag name as a search term. For example [C++ "tagged" jobs](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c++?pg=7) contain [this job](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/53318/devops-architect-workshare-limited) which isn't tagged as C++ at all, and appear in the results due to the sentence "Hacked together a solution for a problem using either Ruby, Java, C++ or Python."

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate of the one about filtering, or close enough to cover the same scenario?